# iPhone-only app orientation controls for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am developing an iOS app and have been told by Apple's app review board that my app has to run properly on iPad as well as iPhone, even though I only intended for it to run on iPhone.

I am having trouble locking the orientation on iPad to landscape. I have set the supported orientations to landscape only in the general settings and in my view controller. I tried doing the same in the info.plist, but when I tried to upload my build, Xcode gave me an error saying that all 4 orientation options had to be enabled.

On iPhone, my app has no issue with orientation. I am wondering if there is a way to force landscape orientation on the iPad that I overlooked and that still allows me to have all 4 orientations selected in the info.plist.

Comment: If your app is an iPhone only app (not universal) then you don't need to do anything specific for the iPad. You do need to ensure that your app works correctly at iPhone 4 resolution as that is the screen size used for an iPhone app on iPad.

Comment: @Paulw11 I had that initially but everything scaled badly. I’ll give it another shot thanks

Comment: In your apps project settings do you have it flagged for iPhone only or as Universal.  If it is flagged as Universal then it needs to work on iPads as well.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I initially had it as iPhone only but when I submitted it for review I was told it had to work on iPad as well, regardless of what my project settings are set to

Comment: In which case it has to be something related to what @Paulw11 has said.  You should have been informed something like this 'We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.2. Specifically, we were unable to register as the sign up option was behind the amount section.'

Comment: That is correct. iPhone only apps can still be installed on an iPad so they must work at iPhone 4 resolution.

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay thanks. I’ll have to take a look at my scaling code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also learned that I can also select the “Requires Full Screen” option in my general settings. This eliminates the need for all 4 orientation options being enabled in the info.plist file, as it disables the option for iPad multitasking. This only applies if the target devices option is flagged as Universal.

Comment: Is this meant to be a solution to your question or is this just further information? If latter, please delete this "answer" and edit your question as needed.